# Auto Cell Height on UITableView without overlapping bottom part of iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, iphone-x

So my goal is to achieve automatic height for my table view. What I mean by by that is whenever I add new item to the table view, the table is still "full screen" while the cell is decreasing its height.

for example this is what I've done :

[on iPhone 6s Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmKRL.png)

[on iPhone 5s Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMOye.png)

and I've achieve that using code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let itemCount:CGFloat = CGFloat(items.count)
    let statusHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    let navHeight = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height-statusHeight
    let viewHeight = view.bounds.height
    let cellHeight = (viewHeight-navHeight)/itemCount
    return cellHeight
}
```

but the problem is that in iPhone X it was doing something like :

[on iPhone X Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPqPV.png)

the bottom part of the bottom item is cut/overlapped. How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Edit :

Thanks for the answer [Trupesh Vaghasiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9331686/trupesh-vaghasiya) and [Pankaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5241821/pankaj) I've done your solution, couldn't find it but this is what I've done {[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcokv.png)}

But the outcome was like this {[iPhone X Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBOTr.png)}. Don't you think that's violates the iPhone X UI guideline?

Comment: Do you want to show 3 Cell ? directly return tableview.frame.height / 3. No need for status bar and etc

Comment: if you've solved the issue on other sized phones the issue should be with the frame of your scrollview not the cells.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the white area in the bottom?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya yes, well, I want it to be dynamic. so whenever I add or remove cell, the cell height will fill up the screen.

Comment: @AlexBailey so by that you mean the problem isn't the cell height, but more like the table height?

Comment: @TienLe yup, well, not really remove it, but decreasing the table height so the white area aren't overlapping the table.

Comment: Because it is safe area. Look back your layout, change to superView instead Safe area

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `TableView` Bottom Constraint **First Item** `Safe Area` to give `SupperView`.

[image]

Let us know... is working?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that soon. I'll inform you if it's working.

Comment: It seems the answer isn't working as I intended. I've edited my answer. could you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your Interface constraint relevant to superView instead of safe area. Check your tableview top and bottom Constraint and make it related to superView. but as per apple said, it is good if you make it related to safe area as iPhone X and higher version have home button on screen so. you can check bellow screen shots. [Select Bottom Constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEq2Z.png)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've done your solution but It seems the answer isn't working as I intended. I've edited my answer. could you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Select `constraint` that you want to change and `Double Click` at there.

[image]

And then select `First Item` and then select `Superview`

[image]

Comment: alright thank you, gonna try it soon. I'll inform you as soon as I implement your answer.